# Laravel + Angular ng-rateIt - Error: ngModel:nonassign Non-Assignable Expression

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I use [this module](https://github.com/akempes/angular-rateit/blob/master/README.md) . I want to fetch rate number from database and use it as model. here is my code:

```
<li><ng-rate-it ng-model="{{ $comment->rate  }}" read-only="true"></ng-rate-it></li>
```

Star rating display but I give an error :

```
Error: ngModel:nonassign
Non-Assignable Expression

Expression '3' is non-assignable. Element: <div
```

In my case *$comment->rate* is equal to '3'.  Why this error display in console and how to solve it ?

**EDITED:**
I feel I should fetch data in my angular controller and bind it as model.

Comment: You are using ng-model="{{ $comment->rate  }}" instead of   ng-model="{{ $comment.rate  }}"

Comment: Yes, you should access rate as `$comment.rate`. Also, what's the reason for prepending `comment` with `$`?

Comment: have you solved your problem maybe? how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

The name of variable in javascript cannot start with number. So what you've written basically is

```
... ng-model="3" ...
```

and ng-model should contain name of the variable in controller that you're trying to use and leverage angulars two-way data binding.
So, in controller:

```
$scope.rating = 3;
```

in view:`

```
<li><ng-rate-it ng-model="{{ rating  }}" read-only="true"></ng-rate-it></li>
```